# Cannot get Broadcom wifi adapter to work under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, broadcom

I have a Packard Bell EasyNote TV 11HC laptop. It has a Broadcom wifi adapter. It came with Linux and I bought Windows 7. After I installed Windows I can't get the wifi adapter to work. I tried to install drivers from the vendor's resource DVD and from official Packard Bell website, but no luck. Where I should start investigating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was - the drivers on the manufacturer's provided resource CD are incorrect. The CD contains only Broadcom and Atheros wifi adapter drivers, but I found out that my laptop actually has a Realtek wifi card. That's why the drivers didn't work.